# Unable to get property 'options' in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript codes here :

```
function setOptDcsn(objID, objSrc){
        var optObj = document.getElementById(objSrc);
        var newCbo = document.getElementById(objID);
        var i;
        var cntOpt=1;
        for (i=0; i<optObj.options.length; i++) {
            newCbo[cntOpt] = new Option(optObj[i].innerHTML,optObj[i].value);
            cntOpt++;
        }  
    }
```

But, when I call that function, it says Error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: share your html and how you are calling the method

Comment: How are you calling that function? Make sure `DOM` is already loaded before calling it (use `window.onload`)

Comment: Instead of `optObj[i].innerHTML` you should use `optObj[i].text`, as option elements don't contain markup. Their content is held in their *text* property. If you are replicating options, consider using [*cloneNode*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-3A0ED0A4): `newCbo[cntOpt] = optObj[i].cloneNode(true)` instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ew6eb5nq/1/ ?

Comment: That error means that the ID in `objSrc` doesn't exist in the DOM when you call this function. So `document.getElementById(objSrc)` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference.

This means `optObj` is null and by implication `document.getElementById(objSrc);` is null and therefore and element by id `objSrc` does not exist.